# 60 kms per hour or an hour

Tags: prepositions

The train is running at a speed of 65 kms per hour.
The train is running at a speed of 65 kms an hour.
Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. So too would be *The train is running at a speed of 65 kph.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "a" and "per" in "miles an/per hour"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156520/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-per)

Comment: The abbreviation of 'kilometres' is 'km', not 'kms'.

Comment: Likewise mm, cm, m, mg, g, kg, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would not go so far as to say either are *incorrect*, but I would say that `per` is the more *accurate* phrasing. ***Why?*** Because in the context of this statement `per` means "for each", and that is precisely what is meant: *the train travels 65 km for each hour*. `an` has no such meaning.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/an) says it has: << **an** preposition .. Definition of _an_ (Entry 2 of 9): (see **a** entry 3 sense 2): {Definition of **a** : in, to, or for each – _twice a week_, [three times an hour]}
_sixty miles an hour_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I saw that, but still feel `per` is more accurate. Do you disagree?

Comment: [These Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sixty+miles+per+hour%2Csixty+miles+an+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csixty%20miles%20per%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csixty%20miles%20an%20hour%3B%2Cc0) show that 'sixty miles an hour' is (and has been for a long time) roughly twice as accurate as 'sixty miles per hour' if the standard used is 'what people actually say'. ELU deals with what people actually say and find acceptable, not in the first instance what some feel better reflects the history of words' meanings.

Comment: '[I]n the context of this statement _per_ means "for each"; _an_ has no such meaning' where a respected dictionary reads 'an preposition: in, to, or for each – twice a week, [three times an hour]} sixty miles an hour' seems the source of the obfuscation here.  I didn't answer because there was (a) a previous identical question and (b) no reasonable research in the question. There's none in your answer, either.